# Saltstack master has dynamic ip address

Tags: saltstack

What is the best way to manage a minions master location when the master within SaltStack has a dynamic IP address?

Is there a way to automatically update the minions (master) IP address?

Comment: Don't use a dynamic IP address?

Comment: Well sometimes you dont have a choice

Answer (score 2):

You can use a hostname in the minion config that is dynamicaly updated each time the ip changes:

```
master: your_hostname.noip.com
```

There is a free service like [noip](http://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/getting-started-with-no-ip-com/) to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Since this question has been raised `salt-ssh` appeared on the stage: http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/ssh/. It is production ready since release 2014.7.0 (October 2014).

In this situation the master uses SSH to connect to the minions. No need for the master to have a static IP address any more.

You don't even need salt installed on the minion. You only need Python on the minion.

Br,
Alexander.